# Why doesn't this code work? (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, file

I have a problem with the following code:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("D:\FrewGame\Game\FrewShort.lnk", "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\" & "Name.lnk")
```

It does not work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Remember you're addressing shortcuts here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it tries to seek help regarding debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the home directory of the current user use:

```
Dim homeDir As String = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE")
```

Then copy the file:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("D:\FrewGame\Game\FrewShort.lnk", homeDir & "\Desktop\" & "Name.lnk")
```

Comment: Ow...
Now i have another problem.
The file 'd:\documente\visual studio 2010\Projects\FrewGame\FrewGame\bin\Debug\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Goat Simulator.lnk' already exists.

Comment: Pretty self explaining if you ask me.

Comment: :)) Yeah Sorry. But i can't see the shortcut